# WebRTC shim for browsers that don't support WebRTC

Tags: webrtc

Not a lot of browsers support WebRTC yet, but there's a lot of cool WebRTC stuff to play with -- PeerDB, etc.

Is there any sort of shim for spoofing a WebRTC API in the browser (so that things like PeerDB will just work), but which actually communicates outside the browser using something other than WebRTC?

Is that even technically feasible? Why or why not?

Answer (score 2):

It's absolutely doable - we're doing it in [IceLink](http://www.frozenmountain.com/downloads#icelink). It uses native support when available, and falls back to a Java applet if native support is unavailable.

Answer (score 0):

For Internet Explorer, Microsoft started defining the [CU-RTC-Web](http://html5labs.interoperabilitybridges.com/prototypes/cu-rtc-web-video/cu-rtc-web-video/info) that will allow basically the same as the current Google specification for WebRTC, but with a different API. (But they do have to be against all standards, so...)

Also for IE, currently you have Google Frame plugin that can be installed to provide the same API's that are available on Google Chrome.

For browsers besides Firefox, Chrome and IE, I don't think there is a current shim other than Flash based applications.

Comment: Chrome Frame is deprecated and as of 2014 no longer supported.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it does what you want, but Doubango Telecom maintain [webrtc4all](https://code.google.com/p/webrtc4all/), which is an extension that aims to provide WebRTC support on browsers that don't yet implement the APIs.

WebRTC works very nicely with Chrome Frame, but that's [due to be retired](http://blog.chromium.org/2013/06/retiring-chrome-frame.html) in January 2014.